# Convert images to PDF

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, pdf-generation, batch-processing

## What I am looking for

**I want to put several images in a PDF file, with `ImageMagick`** (preferably), as follows:

- One image per page,
- each page in the PDF **must** have A4 size,
- image size (in pixels) may be shrunk but never enlarged,
- max size for an image is 1240x1753 pixels (max DPI target is 150); such dimensions would fill the whole A4 page,
- if an image is smaller than the dimensions stated above, it is not resized (it doesn't matter if it appears as big as a shrunk image),
- the image must be centred on each page,
- no addition of white pixels around the image to make it "fit the page",
- images must be jpeg (quality 80) to limit PDF file size.

## What I tried (part of)

So far, I am using this:

```
convert small.png big1.jpeg big2.jpeg -compress jpeg -quality 80 -resize '1240x1753>' -page A4 out.pdf
```

### The result

That kind of works but:

- the small image is not centred: it's on the bottom left corner of the page,
- the pages don't appear with the same size on my PDF reader (first page is smaller),
- `pdfinfo out.pdf | grep -a size` says `Page size: 112.441 x 159.118 pts` but with an A4 page generated from LibreOffice it says `Page size: 595.304 x 841.89 pts (A4)`

### Other attempts

I have tried playing with `-gravity` and `-density` but they produce weird results in my tests: they seem to apply to the whole PDF, and either make the images being half outside the page (with `-gravity`) or just my PDF reader making the same document appear very far when I first open it with (`-density`), so that I need to zoom.

`-extent` is probably excluded as it adds pixels to the images (around them).

## My request

How can I do that with ImageMagick or `convert`? (or potentially, together with one or several other simple command line tool(s))

I'm not seeking recommendation. I have a problem and one sophisticated tool (ImageMagick). I'm pretty sure the tool can solve the problem, but I don't know how to use it to do so.

Comment: Sometimes people vote to close when they don’t know how to answer a question. This question is clearly within the scope of Stack Overflow, it is well researched and clear, there is no reason to close it.

Comment: @KJ so… you’re saying you don’t know how to do it? Maybe it cannot be done. But that is a valid answer, not a reason to close the question as opinion-based.

Comment: @KJ If it cannot be done then an answer is an explanation of why it cannot be done. That can be a statement backed up by facts. The "opinion based" close reason is for questions that lead to answers of the type "I prefer this tool" and "I think this other tool is more fun". An answer that says "this tool cannot do this because of ...." is a valid and valuable answer.

Comment: Hello @KJ, I updated my question to allow other "simple" command line tools to be used together with `ImageMagick`, if that helps feasibility.